# Forced into roaming

Tags: roaming

I have a HTC One M7 that I use on Sprint. My issue is that I am forced to have my phone in roam mode for it to function. I currently have Automatic selected because in Home only mode I have no communications at all. The phone is rooted and also s-off.

Thanks in advance for any help someone can give me.